# Targeting different providers per logger

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it not possible to target different logging providers based on which logger is used?

For example, refer to the below code:

```
// Establish loggers
var someLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("SomeLogger");
var anotherLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("AnotherLogger");

// Hook up providers (but not at the individual logger's level??)
loggerFactory.AddDebug(minimumLevel: LogLevel.Debug);
loggerFactory.AddConsole(minimumLevel: LogLevel.Debug);
loggerFactory.AddBlob(connectionString, minimumLevel: LogLevel.Information);

// Log stuff
someLogger.LogError("Logging with someLogger");
anotherLogger.LogError("Logging with anotherLogger");
```

All providers will be logged too here, regardless of which logger is used.

Is this really not possible?  What is the point of defining separate loggers if they all log to every provider regardless?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's possible but what you can do is log messages of different log levels to different providers. The example below logs all warning level messages and above to the event log using the `SourceSwitch` API. The use case here which may satisfy your needs is that you may not want information or debug messages filling up your event log.

```
private static void ConfigureLogging(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var sourceSwitch = new SourceSwitch("EventLog");
    sourceSwitch.Level = SourceLevels.Warning;
    loggerFactory.AddTraceSource(sourceSwitch, new EventLogTraceListener("Application"));
}
```

**UPDATE**

ASP.NET 5 is very light on examples at the moment but the `AddProvider` method on `ILoggerFactory` is used to add it's own custom providers specific to it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used to create logger instances of the given name.
/// </summary>
public interface ILoggerFactory : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The minimum level of log messages sent to registered loggers.
    /// </summary>
    LogLevel MinimumLevel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new ILogger instance of the given name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="categoryName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName);

    void AddProvider(ILoggerProvider provider);
}
```

So you could create another `ILoggerFactory` but register different providers to it. Then inject the right `ILoggerFactory` into your classes depending on where you want to log to.

Comment: Yeah, logging by level is straight forward enough.  But I still don't understand the purpose of having different loggers if you cannot define independently define how they function.

Comment: Good Question. I've updated my answer. There might be a way if you use another instance of `ILoggerFactory`.